# Read First Data Value Of Firebase Child

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a child in my Firebase Database that includes messages from one device to another. I'd like to be able to access the first message. Because each message child name is a random key, I cannot search for the message by key. Is there any way to retrieve the first value of a child?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to access the first child in my database by using an Iterator.

```
Iterator i = dataSnaphot.getChildren().iterator();
```

I called `i.next()` to get the first element.

Comment: @cricket_007 I did see that in another question but I couldn't get it to work for some reason.